# linker command failed with exit code 1 for arc i368

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

hi while running the app i am facing this error:

```
`/Users/sandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dump-dthllbuozjssjoaoxafcckvdapti/Build/Intermediates/dump.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/dump.build/Objects-normal/i386/main.o
/Users/sandeep/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/dump-dthllbuozjssjoaoxafcckvdapti/Build/Intermediates/dump.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/dump.build/Objects-normal/i386/FSExtractor.o`

ld: 1 duplicate symbol for architecture i386
```

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Hi every one thanks for comments and there is such a file with same name and its about .c and .h file, i imported .h file only but still i am getting that error, not getting any idea how to clear it

Comment: Go to the command line, `cd` into the source directory and post the output from `grep main *`.

Comment: First Check Some you use `#import file.m` instead of `#import file.h` mat be this issue.

Comment: Its saying for duplicate file in your project, Search file "FSExtractor" name in your bundle and check there should be more than one file. So keep only one.